# Data Preperation Identify String using Regex and move to new column

Tags: regex, talend

Hello I am using Talend to prepare product data for import into DB. I want to use the extract string parts function for Talend.

I have the following data in one cell. (The length of the data varies not a fixed width format)

> Measurement: Ring Head Width: 6.8 Ring Height: 5.5 Ring Shank Width: 1.1 Ladies Band Width: 2.5 Ladies band shank Width: 1.2

I need help creating a regex format to match each measurement value and extract it to a new column.

What would be Regex to match the following text ?

> Ring Head Width: 6.8

and extract the numeric value following it, which is

> 6.8

Similarly I want to create regex for all the above measurements. I am assuming the format will be the same.

Thank for your time and help.

Comment: Tried `Ring Head Width: (\d+(\.\d+)?)`

Comment: Thanks. The Regex checks out but the Talend software is not extracting the values based of Regex code. Posted the issue in their forums.

https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=195547#p195547

Answer (score 0):

If you don't bother using multiple actions to acheive this result I suggest that you use:

- the "Split text in parts" action on ":"
- and then use "remove whitespaces" to have a clean value.

If you really need to keep one action, you have the "Remove part of the text" action on regex that is based on the java [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Using regex "**.*:\s**" works fine